# Dotnetnuke community installation

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

I have a dontnuke community website that was built long time ago. I have been task to migrate the website from windows server 2008 to 2012. I copied the website from 2008 server to 2012 and I create the website on IIS. I am getting an error on Configure Database Connection

```sh
Connection Error(s):
Index #: 0
Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider
Class: 20
Number: 53
Message:
```

[image: Please see screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

See if you can connect to the database using the data from your connection string using Sql Server Management Studio.  That might give you a better clue.

Comment: Yes I can connect to the database using Sql Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Model the DNN connection string based on your SSMS credentials.  Did you run SSMS on the server that runs the website?  Did you verify that you can open tables and edit them?

Comment: Let me try to install SSMS on the server and try to connect to the database. Currently, I can connect using SSMS from my local computer to the database server using connection string credentials.

Comment: Hi Joe, thank you very much. I after I installed SSMS to the server and try to connect I got a proper error message and the problem was that I was using the alias server name instead of IP address. After I changed to use IP address everything went well. Thank you again.

Comment: You can use the alias name when you add it to the hosts file (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts) - just use a text editor to add the line...